# Twitter "confirm e-mail" message won't disappear

Tags: twitter

I've just created a Twitter account and on my home page I get a yellow message saying that I must still confirm my e-mail address.

I do have a message in my inbox but when I click the link it just says "already confirmed". The message mentioned earlier still won't go away. When I click the "resend confirmation mail" button, it says that there was an error re-sending.

What can I do to make it go away?

I've logged out and in again, no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter has a page listing things to try if you have [trouble confirming your email address](https://support.twitter.com/articles/82050-i-m-having-trouble-confirming-my-email-address). Based on what you've already done, it sounds like you need to:

> Wait a few days, then click the 'Resend confirmation' link in the
>   yellow nag at the top of your Twitter home page again. We send the
>   emails immediately when you create your account, but it is possible
>   that your email provider was temporarily blocking emails from us or
>   delivery was delayed.

If that still doesn't do it, they have a form to [contact them for help](https://support.twitter.com/forms/signin).